# Detecting areas in an image. Overlapping Widgets in QT is it possible ?

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have an image say of a face displayed inside a QLabel and I would like to add two QPushButtons on the eye so that I would know when those buttons are pressed.I would like to have the buttons overlap the face so I would know that the user clicked on the eye. My question is if there is a Layout in QT that would allow overlapping of widgets. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the parent of the `QPushButtons` to the `QLabel`, and then use `setGeometry(x, y, w, h)` to specify the `QPushButton`'s location and size within the QLabel.

```
QPushButton * leftEyeButton = new QPushButton(ui->myLabel);
leftEyeButton ->setGeometry(5,10,20,20);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this through the designer

Comment: Not that I am aware of, unfortunately. Qt Designer does not support parenting to a QLabel since it also doesn't support applying a layout to QLabels. You'll have to do it in code.